# How do I list direct children of home page?

Tags: wagtail

I have the following in my `base.html` before the `content` block.

```
{% for page in homepage.get_children.specific %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">{{ page }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, this displays nothing. How do I set things up so that every page displays the children of the home page and links to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails because `homepage` is not defined. `request.site.root_page` will give you the page object you're looking for:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% for page in request.site.root_page.get_children.specific %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% pageurl page %}">{{ page.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here we're using Wagtail's `{% pageurl %}` tag to output the link URLs.